# Submenu not dropping down but appearing next to parent menu

Tags: html, css

I am preparing a blogger template. And the navigation menu creating problems. Submenu appearing next to parent menu. But not dropping down. 
Have a look at [testblogorfy.blogspot.com](http://testblogorfy.blogspot.com).
View CSS via "pagesource"--> #menu or "header-navigation"

Comment: Please provide some example code. It will be easier to analyse and help you with your problem.

Comment: it looks like your throwing them all inside the same tag. Without a code example its hard to see where your going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can read this link for more clarification `https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp.`

For your support I have paste the same code from the above link.
Basically for sub menu, you have to create another ul nested within the li element.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't just add links , in time the link may be unresolved (404), which dosen't help future people looking for an answer to this question

Comment: happy days!, you may get down votes if you just add links lol